# Homebrew installation stuck at make install. How do I resolve?

Tags: imagemagick, homebrew

I am trying to install `imagemagick` using `homebrew`:

```
sudo brew install imagemagick
```

It gets stuck at:

```
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/libtool/2.4.2 --program-prefix=g --en
==> make install
```

How do I debug this? How do I install imagemagick?

Answer (score 1):

Try `brew reinstall imagemagick`

I also encountered the same problem while trying to install node via `brew install node`. So, I just tried `brew reinstall node` and it worked for me.

Comment: Facing same issue for node. unfortunately `brew reinstall node` is not working for me

Answer (score 1):

Try with -v parameter to show more information during installation:

```
brew reinstall -v imagemagick
```